# Convert for loop to List Comprehension Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

The problem is for all the numbers (1 - 20) the highest single digit (1 - 9) of any of the numbers is divisible by.

I have a for loop as given below:

```
values = [[] for value in range(1, 11)]

for num in range(1, 21):
    highest = 0
    for div in range(1, 10):
        if(num % div == 0 and div > highest):
            highest = div
    
    values[highest].append(num)
```

The following for loop output:

```
[[], [1, 11, 13, 17, 19], [2], [3], [4], [5, 10, 15, 20], [6, 12], [7, 14], [8, 16], [9, 18]]
```

The empty list [] that in the output can be ignored. For example:

```
[[1, 11, 13, 17, 19], [2], [3], [4], [5, 10, 15, 20], [6, 12], [7, 14], [8, 16], [9, 18]]
```

I want to convert the following for loop to list comprehension, can anyone please help me.

Comment: I don't believe it's that simple - you do appending on index and it's the index that needs calculating via additional loop... What do you think about dict comprehension (dict pairing number to its `highest`) and then "flipping" it?

Comment: You can do it if you'll change logic a bit: `nums = list(range(1, 21)) ; values = [[nums.pop(i) for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1) if not nums[i] % d] for d in range(9, 0, -1)]`. But it will generate list in reversed order.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Wrap it into `reversed` (and do `range(9, -1, -1)` to not skip index 0) and it will be what OP needs. Post it as an answer! | Now excuse me, I need to take my time to understand how you did that because it's amazing! :D

Comment: @h4z3, I actually know how to do this, decided to leave this for OP. Also, changing to  `range(9, -1, -1)` is very bad idea, you can say why.

Comment: The question is: Why do you want it as a list comprehension? It will loose readability and not gain anything.

Comment: @OlvinRoght ... Oh, right. %0. At this point there are no numbers left so it works anyways. I just tried to smartass my way around adding [] at 0 index. I want to become your level at listcomp, seriously, your solution is so nice.

Comment: @h4z3, just add `+ [[]]` at the end ;-)

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thank you for your solution but I don't need it in reverse order, I have tried for 2 days to find any way to solve it with a list comprehension. Note time complexity is not a problem just want to solve the problem.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I know, I just said I tried to do it in smartass way, to keep it inside comprehension still. :P

Comment: @TempleVersion, it's easy to make in proper order if you add two calls of `reversed()`.

Comment: @h4z3, try `import this`. Take a look on second rule. My solution is bad, because it's way too implicit and you want to make it even more complex. List comprehension is not good solution for this particular problem, 3 lines of code with `for` loop is.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I know the Zen. Doesn't change the fact that I think your solution"nice" (I never said readable or good, especially for this problem + I even wrote I need to take time to understand it ;) ). "Nice" because as I wrote my comments before you, I could only do it as dict comprehension or triple list comprehension (the listcomp comment I deleted after seeing your solution, dictcomp comment is still there) and I just want to be able to think like that (not necessarily write that in production code ;) )

Comment: @OlvinRoght give your solution in the answer, not in comments, I will vote. Your solution is great. Nice work.

Comment: @TempleVersion, I've posted my answer and added some measurements, take a look

Comment: Why the ` and div > highest`? How could that every be false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need the first empty list? The solution proposed by @Olvin makes clever use of `pop`. You'll have to reverse it to get what you want though.

Here a solution that might be easier to understand and gives you the result you expect:

```
print([ [num for num in range(1,21) if num % div == 0 and all(num % x != 0 for x in range(div + 1, 10)) ] for div in range(1,10)])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 11, 13, 17, 19], [2], [3], [4], [5, 10, 15, 20], [6, 12], [7, 14], [8, 16], [9, 18]]
```

The use of `all` will generate more computing time (so will reverse in the other solution).
It's fun to create comprehension if you want to train but loops are fine as well. And here much easier to read!

###### EDIT

Since so many people commented on the question and my answer I started to look closer to the problem and timed all solutions. It turns out @Olvin's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69841746/13525512) is the fastest and matches the speed of OP's loop. Followed by my solution (approx. 3x slower on my machine) and @JonSG's solution (9x slower) turns out reversing the lists is much better optimized than I thought...

Comment: *"might be easier to understand"* - doubt that, mine is complex too. List comprehension is just not a way to go here.

Comment: well I also wrote "might" ;-) Loved your solution though! I said it might be easier to understand cause it's closer to the initial loop structure actually

Comment: @Tranbi Thank you for your solution. This will work. List comprehension is not for this problem, it's making complex.

Answer (score 4):

*The problem is for all the numbers (1 - 20) the highest single digit (1 - 9) of any of the numbers is divisible by.*

I'd implement it in another way using `list.pop()`:

```py
nums = list(range(1, 21))
values = []
for d in range(9, 0, -1):
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):  # iterating in reverse order
        if not nums[i] % d:  # nums[i] % d == 0
            temp.insert(0, nums.pop(i))
    values.insert(0, temp)
print(values)
```

Basically, we initialize list of numbers from `1` to `20` and pop value which divisible by digit. I used `list.insert()` here to make it produce result in same order as your solution.

In [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69840562/10824407#comment123454744_69840562) I posted code which will produce list in reversed order, here is it:

```py
nums = list(range(1, 21))
values = [[nums.pop(i) for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1) if not nums[i] % d] for d in range(9, 0, -1)]
```

You can add two calls of [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) *(as i suggested in [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69840562/10824407#comment123455163_69840562))* or reverse it using slicing to make it return list in proper order:

```py
nums = list(range(1, 21))
values = [[nums.pop(i) for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1) if not nums[i] % d][::-1] for d in range(9, 0, -1)][::-1]
```

---

**Upd.** I've decided to add some tests result which should help to see why list comprehension doesn't make it any better. If you want to reproduce tests, code is [here](https://tio.run/##vVbbjpswEH3nK9ysqoU2FyCEJEjpQ18qtVIrtVVfEELs4iTWgqHgpNmvT21zs4Ek9MpLFHvmnJnjmbHTZ7JP8HyVZudzCLcgSYmhag4Ad2BPSJo7s1lOgsen5AizbZT8mD4m8ez7zF6vLH1hmzNDX5mWpS8VQL9jEB1gDjbAdT2wTbJiASAMsgDvoGqMgWFonsKN2T4@xNKuaWgO32TfHu32MCcUTq/XmFOIjjKkLjixD22BypBfctMN9QcBDvmfNxVqy0Xmo5ZKvV0k5Za73jRIU4hDRqAVRhkkhwyXdopSqmjeVDHgKhr6fCGrWOK5dQSuFCrLrNROzrqRhMrYFqSrh2QRRFEp2Qm8YAaM4dRgMsfXoBC7wfaunQu1VAqjSpL5UEksff23JQE9miAcwhPTIw5OqtupB8QxUXddrr3uPlU7IaXisrsnaFegsxDGwFcEcEg9YRYQqIpd0xbT@g9iDhYQwxNRS70ap/UY6GMwMbSWJL0iCFydwlkMzXVp2XKulJHNowjlRBUz0VrzyqtHUtgTfzMrCIzTxr7yEXKOIGaNlGtgwtplYhQALHpE2KkivOPWkIafQ5BkIcyU/vLJXeSxpuXewn/ewp2yY6FNEc5hRlQaNrOfpkmqIqFhi4QFK@Z0dYzZ/0j620VYRT9M4RsSNhXnOs7EaA2uniNXRONajeXvXI13dD2GmBjm3FosbXvuV4JxkpAX4McEQw@8ogL1VWL7lmPbQneGTNgxCFuXWpi7sceus1Lx/BAR4XL2pZZrOiAeF9TNHKJAhuPRGASCAs4N6wsxlg622K6FW/2xcCvLWsvCDX1tcCnQkVmSQxpVY7U@am3Yc0S44hiao1yc@XS7@7p4yGDw1H5UUEv5QdHTiBTa93EQQ99njX/v@3GAsO/fFxwoTpOMAIJiiAhfSTOEiTr6Sls7guAbHTMowc5oXNpMix91VDz16HpOCdPNaJslMajQK1xmNOLT5AFmG0OnXylYRUPVekD98OYQePMq/PsEf3nXjz4fgj6/ja6@Bp@iI8JaP401hMa6SsPhwedktydAPRoXiBZDiBa/QGReILKHENlXiT7AKHoGbw84fO7nWA7hWF6vLKmA6Slx0gs5rYbwrTp85/NP).

**Tests results** *(lower is better)*:

```
Temple Version: 0.49361748499999997
Tranbi: 1.794325605
JonSG: 5.4978652320000005
JonSG(+ Olvin): 4.834248347000001
Olvin Roght (v1): 0.34827960000000147
Olvin Roght (v2): 0.4133600079999997
Kelly Bundy: 0.19429717999999951
Temple Version(+ Kelly): 0.20479166999999876
```

Comment: [old Greek way](https://tio.run/##jZLbasMwDIbv8xSiY8wZaZN0pWkDeYUNdhuMyWanNYsPOG7Lnr5TTj2wXcwQEvuXv19SZL/93uiXjXXnMxc1GOvXJMwBHmDvvW3zOG599flljsLVjTktPo2Kq3i93azSbLWO02SzXK2SLABc@qBaKKCRrSeu0jtB0giWaRj2qhP@4DSU/aZb16/p8sIaS2QItXEgQWoYKI3QpJNDmAMS5/0T3t2WNWjje0gpKTwCv8i0zPN5Si/7Ds6v8G0EyZU3BQdjMzJsRi/wrrLy1WhB4RmLCv5AYV5pMsZPsrrKvGtGBPwmYiCXiiKcj11qD43vvEraA9gNPwnpxVdFg7XAmoWrPPLbMs0p5nBjMOBKTheVtUJzou5@xiAHAbaPMV0pwRgUBTwxpiqpGXsaSFJZ4zx4qYT0/Yl1Unsye2uOmMK72e09kOMyzGfRGLUYXmQ2TBSet2hpi1ntjIKJP5G7IAzBUj6EK9IE1zg1FyMOOyfEF5yqbxxP@NMo@49R9svofP4B)

Comment: @KellyBundy, those old greeks were smart! Added your method to comparison. Consider posting it as answer, that's a good option.

Comment: Btw, replacing the OP's `(num % div == 0 and div > highest)` with `not num % div` seems to make it about as fast as yours.

Comment: @KellyBundy, could be, did not investigate. Reverting loop logic with `break` could also make it faster. List relocation is not cheap, so mine solution is not fastest obviously, at least in Python.

Comment: Right, further optimized OP's [almost catches mine](https://tio.run/##jVJLa4QwEL77K4aFslrsYrqHbQUvvRZ6Kr2IBJfENtQ8iHFhf72dGLVaCu1cAjNfvsck5uo@tDo@GDsMjDegjSNxkkeAdanbnndQQFlW0GgbGiAU2Fq985ikQEhSjVgmLh7petPyOIwfU8hSuCNJMiI8gerl5vo9maRmANJ4gGf7HvgSDSjtRoIbP95OfZ0trz@XbvBeIrI61MZwxWK8G5xY7nqrJkgUTbFPc2w2Rn7RildwixYX92wbPfvhfRWN@WgpsGRrk3WlrJCcTTa6vnWr9dIVfzbtdSROgzTHBNzWDvm7kuQVelgJBLqSLXm3acM4inCRlKpackqhKGBPqayFonQfmIQ02jpwQnLhFgcrZ8eVpLFCuXj3yiW@Orxx2wmtcoBdOhEcwhHvwrfCfoduTLFrrJYwS8@iHoQQTHnmtiAZ1vR3VmLPvG2v8NQrds3H/q9ip/@Inf4SS4bhCw).

Comment: Meh, won't post as answer, since the question is explicitly all about list comprehension and I don't have one (other than my `result = [[] for _ in range(10)]` :-).

Comment: @KellyBundy, I assume *(from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69840562/10824407#comment123455496_69841035))* that OP give up with list comprehension, so your answer will be quite useful

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, they wrote that before the "JonSG(+ Olvin)" solution was posted. I think that's a decent list comp solution and a good answer to the question as asked. It's slower, but they also said *"Note time complexity is not a problem just want to solve the problem"*.

Comment: Oh, Tranbi's solution (where they commented what you linked to) would also be good if they hadn't put it all in one long physical line. Maybe then the OP wouldn't have given up on it...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different take on the comprehension.

```
values = [
    [
        num for num
        in range(1, 21)
        if index == max([
            i for i
            in range(1, 10)
            if not num%i
        ])
    ] for index, _
    in enumerate(range(1, 11))
]
print(values)
```

This will give you:

```
[[], [1, 11, 13, 17, 19], [2], [3], [4], [5, 10, 15, 20], [6, 12], [7, 14], [8, 16], [9, 18]]
```

It can be simplified a bit but I was attempting to match what you had done as closely as I could.

Here is a straightforward simplification and improvement as highlighted by @olvin-roght:

```
values = [
    [
        num for num in range(1, 21)
        if index == next(i for i in range(9, 0, -1) if not num%i)
    ] for index in range(10)
]
```